# TinyMCE Insert/Edit Image

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Currently my application is using TinyMCE version 3.x and
I'm upgrading it to 4.3.2, I have the below issue.
In my existing version 3.x, if I click on insert/edit image there will be a dialog box opened with below options

[image: Tiny MCE Insert/Edit Dialog 3.x Version]

When I integrate the tinymce version 4.3.2 and if I click on Insert/Edit image I'm getting a dialog box as shown below

[image: Tiny MCE Insert/Edit 4.3.2 version]

My integration code of tinymce 4.3.2 with my application

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        toolbar: "image searchreplace",
        plugins: "image imagetools searchreplace wordcount"
    });
```

What should I need to do to get the Upload option icon in the latest version

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea', // change this value according to your HTML
  file_picker_types: 'file image media'
});
```

Comment: If I give anyother value than 'textarea' for selector, I'm getting a blank editor in blue colour and all the menu, plugin and toolbar are lost. I'm using firefox for testing the tinymce integration.